# Highlighting the whole row when selected in ListView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

How do I highlight the whole row when selected in ListView Windows Form App? I set the `ListView1.FullRowSelect = True` , `ListView1.GridLines = True` , and using `List` for my `view` but when I select the item, only the icon with text is selected. I'm not sure either using **List** as view is correct or not because some said it is not able to select the whole row if using it. But if I use others such as **Details** or **Tile** my icon will disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `Details` view you have to add some columns to your `ListView` control.

```
ListView1.Columns.Add("col1")
ListView1.Columns.Add("col2")
```

Don't forget to set `ListView1.FullRowSelect = True`, otherwise it won't select the whole row.

To auto size the columns width, set the width foreach column to -1.

```
For Each col As ColumnHeader In ListView1.Columns
    col.Width = -1
Next
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion just now and **Yes** it does select the whole row. Is that means I only need to play with the column?

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "play with the column"?

Comment: All I need to do is only adding the column at ListView, is it? Is that the only way to select the whole row? Because I add all my item inside the ListView dynamically, which is I stored my data using array and display them using loop. So if I add column inside my ListView, my icon and it's text will only displayed in first column.

Comment: Well, I don't know if it's the only way, but it's the only what which I know from my experience. Is there a problem with adding your data dynamically?

Comment: Not really, but got a bit problem with item arrangement when I add column at my ListView. If that's the only way then maybe I need to do some editing on my coding to arrange my added item in ListView. By the way, how to resize the width of the column if I add it into my ListView?

Comment: See my edit, I added the resizing part. What is your big problem with adding items?